# Migrating a Classic ASP app from 2003/IIS7 to 2012/IIS8

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm all but completely new to ASP/.NET. We've got some pressure to move an app because it's currently on a non ipv6 compatible system (the 2003/IIS7). I've got ASP pages getting processed fine, but it would seem any of the more involved apps (possibly just the ones that have Access databases?) are giving me a "500 - Internal server error."

I'm thinking that it might be a permissions issue, or at least that's part of it. If I go to the site remotely, I get that error. If I go to the site on the server is hosted from, I get all of the page loaded until, what seems to be, the first html element that would require options from the DB.

As far as I can tell, all the permissions from the old server are there (the contents was all copied directly over), with one being a phantom user (one of those 234-234-23423423-234-23 type of users.) I've determined that it's the "ASPNET" user... but I haven't been able to find out how to get that user in 2012. Some stuff I was reading suggests that it's been, more or less, removed/changed to something else, and one of our guys here says it was moved in to the Network Services permission (I'm not sure if he meant that he did it, or if it was MS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you moved from a 32 bit to a 64 bit platform.  Both the OLEDB and the ODBC drivers for JET (Access) databases are 32 bit only - and the solution may be to open IIS manager and enable 32 bit applications in your app pool.

If you follow the instructions on this page you will get more helpful error messages than "500 internal server error"

http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: We have. And I realize it never "just works" to do so, but I never know when that issue is going to pop up. I'll try this and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: At the risk of getting ahead of myself (because the page is loading fully now, but I haven't done a ton testing), it works! Thanks! I'd give you 10 vote ups if I could.